# In Java, how do I parse a string bigger than int size

Tags: java, parsing

I have a string bigger than 2,147,483,647 and I need to parse it. Integer.parseInt doesn't do they job, it throws an exception.

Comment: What do you intend to store into? A `long`? Or a `BigInteger`?

Comment: Then use [`Long.parseLong`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong%28java.lang.String%29)???

Comment: what is minimum and maximum value that the number within that string can be?

Comment: Your question needs clarification: 1) is 2^31-1 a reference to the string's size or your numeric's range? 2) What do you want to store it in (long, int, BigInteger, custom numeric class, etc...)? Bigger than 2^31-1 is one thing, but do you know how big it can be? 4) Signed or unsigned? Without more details, Jon's answer is your solution.

Comment: Use a data type which stores larger values e.g. long, double or BigDecimal.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Integer.parseInt` *couldn't* do the job, unless you were happy to lose data. Think about what you're asking for here.

Try [`Long.parseLong(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong%28java.lang.String%29) or [`new BigInteger(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger%28java.lang.String%29) for really big integers.

Answer (score 1):

There's another type called a [Long](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html) which can store numbers up to `2^63 - 1`. Try parsing the string using [`java.text.NumberFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) into a long:

```
    NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance(java.util.Locale.US);

    Number number = format.parse("2,147,483,647");
    Long value = number.longValue();
```

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood what `parseLong` did, I edited the answer with a different solution.

Comment: Or just use `Long.parseLong("2147483648")`.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you went for String because int can't hold your value. It's not needed. You can use BigInteger directly, which can handle significantly larger values.